# pointer to const and const pointer to something

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

what is the difference between

```
const int d=1;
const int *p = &d;
```

and

```
const int d=1;
int const *p = &d;
```

What can I do with the former and the latter ?

Comment: Note that `int* const p` *is* different.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference, they're completely identical.

The grammar of the language simply allows a certain amount of freedom for certain constructions, and CV-qualification of types is one of those situations. There are other examples (e.g. declarations like  `foo typedef int;`).

Answer (score 0):

`const int *p;`

The declaration above declares a pointer `p` that points to a constant `int`. In other words, you can't change the value of the referand but you can change `p` itself.

`int* const p;`

The declaration above declares a constant  pointer `p` that points to an `int`. In other words, you can change the value of the referand, but you can't change `p`. Also,

```
const int d = 1;
int * const p = &d;
```

is not legal. Taking the address of `d` yields `const int*`, and coversion from `const int*` to `int*` is not allowed (you could inadvertedly change the value of a constant object if it were).

You could make the conversion explicitly by using `const_cast`:

```
const int d = 1;
int * const p = const_cast<int*>(&d);
```

but it would still be illegal (undefined behaviour) to change the value of `d` through `p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int *p;
```

`p` is a pointer to a constant integer. You can change the value stored in `p` (thus it point somewhere else) but you can't change the value where `p` points to.

```
int* const p;
```

`p` is a constant pointer to a non constant integer. You can't change the value of `p`, but change the integer where it points to